# Transport.send(message) is not working

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

am sending automatic mail using the bellow code,it will send mail some times and it will get stuck at Transport.send(message) line some times.so am not able to completely relay on this for sending mail automatically can any one help me to solve the issue .

```
           // Create a default MimeMessage object.
          ZipFolder.zipmyfolder(sResultReportFoldernew);
          //ZipFolder.zipmyfolder(resultscreenshotfilepath);


         Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         String filepathtomail1 = sResultReportFoldernew+".zip";
         String baseurl33=urlsplit(baseurl1);
         //String baseurl33=baseurl1;
         sCurTime=ApplicationIndependent.getDateTime("dd-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss z");

         message.setSubject("Automation results for "+baseurl33+" "+sCurTime);

         // Create the message part
         BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Now set the actual message
         messageBodyPart.setText("please find the bellow attachment for the test excecution report");

         // Create a multipar message
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

         // Set text message part
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // Part two is attachment

         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         String filepathtomail2 =resultscreenshotfilepath+".zip";
         System.out.println("--------------------------beforee calling add attach");
         addAttachment(multipart,filepathtomail1,baseurl1);
     // Send the complete message parts
         message.setContent(multipart);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
```

Comment: You say it gets stuck sometimes. Does it crash? Does it throw an exception (with a message)? Does it hang indefinitely? If it only happens sometimes my hunch is that it's something do with your mail server rather than the Java code.

Comment: am not getting any exception ,but mail will not be sent

Comment: Hard to diagnose. I would put that code into a test program and run it with a debugger to see what's going on. I think it must eventually throw an exception if it 'gets stuck', most programs will time out eventually. What happens on your outgoing mail server? Can you see anything in the logs?

Comment: Sometimes pulling thread dumps while program stuck will give you great insight of where in send() (Socket IO?!) you're stuck.

Comment: same code am using in one more project ,in in hat project  not even once also mail have not sent,all the lines of code above transport.send();will be executed properly.but not from that line

Comment: First, turn on [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to see what happens when it "fails".  Is it just getting stuck?  Is the server accepting the message but never delivering it?  Most likely you're going to want to set the [`mail.smtp.connectiontimeout`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.connectiontimeout) and [`mail.smtp.timeout`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.timeout) properties.

Comment: add some debug outputs at some line and find out which line stucked, perhaps you'll get some hint